# How to subset() with factors?

Tags: r, subset, glm

I'm running GLMs in R but need to try some models without one level of the factor Year.

It's like:

```
Year<-as.factor(c(1996,1997,1998,1999,2000))
Shr<-as.numeric(c(1,32,1,50,42))
#... and other variables.
```

How do I 'exclude' only 1998 from my model?
I need to take the whole row from all the others variables as well or the GLM won´t run because of difference on the number of rows.

Comment: Are your variables in a data.frame (as they should be)?

Comment: yes. After inserting all my variables I put them in all<data.frame(Year, Shr...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even more easily, you can just use the `subset` argument of `glm()`:

```
glm(...,data=all,subset=(Year != 1998))
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have your data in a data.frame called `da.fr`, you can use

```
da.fr2<-da.fr[da.fr$Year!=1998,]

da.fr2$Year<-droplevels(da.fr2$Year)
```

The first line makes a new data.frame without any of the 1998 data. The second line will remove 1998 as a factor in Year, as it is no longer in the dataset.

Comment: No problem - if you are doing an analysis using functions without an easy subset option - this is a good way to go.

Answer (score 1):

```
Year<-as.factor(c(1996,1997,1998,1999,2000))
Shr<-as.numeric(c(1,32,1,50,42))

dat <- data.frame(Year=Year, Shr = Shr) # your data
#> dat
#  Year Shr
#1 1996   1
#2 1997  32
#3 1998   1
#4 1999  50
#5 2000  42

> levels(dat$Year)
#[1] "1996" "1997" "1998" "1999" "2000"
```

Depending on what you want to achieve you can:

```
dat2 <- dat[!(dat$Year %in% "1998") , ] # remove rows with 1998
#> dat2
#  Year Shr
#1 1996   1
#2 1997  32
#4 1999  50
#5 2000  42

levels(dat2$Year)
#[1] "1996" "1997" "1998" "1999" "2000" # the 1998 level remains
```

but you can also:

```
dat2$Year <- factor(dat2$Year) # also remove the level if you want
levels(dat2$Year)
#[1] "1996" "1997" "1999" "2000"
```

Comment: Thanks! I will keep this way in mind to other analysis. Really helpful.